# Getting back specific lower bounds value from inputted key in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, collections, linkedhashmap

I have an LinkedHashMap that uses the values from a char array as its key adds integers 1 to the size of the char array as its values:

```
hmConvert = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (int m = 0; m < referenceString.length; m++) {
    hmConvert.put(referenceString[m], m);
}
```

an example of values in the char array would be:

```
'0', '1', '5', '3', '6', '6', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '0', '3', '3', '5'
```

When i use the get method on the LinkedHashMap it is returns the higest key back, for example:

```
int test = hmConvert.get(5);
System.out.println(test);
```

The output would be: 14

I need the output in this case to be the LOWEST value after a GIVEN input value. So if I inputted 4 as the input, the returned value would be 8.

How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first of all, I assume you mean `int test = hmConvert.get('5');`, because in your example, it would be `null`, not `14`.

You can accomplish this goal simply by putting the values in backwards (so the first keys are the ones that don't get overwritten). In other words, do this:

```
for (int m = referenceString.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
  hmConvert.put(referenceString[m], m);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean't '5'. Also, this works great, but one last requirement that I haven't been able to figure out. It is now finding the lowest key but how do I find the lowest key after a specific given index?

Comment: change `m >= 0` to `m => specificIndex`